# nftables setting result in DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Tags: port, nftables

Here is my nftables configuration file:

```
sudo cat /etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        iif lo accept
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

When i open webpage with firefox,it encounters :

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET
```

,i have not close port 80,why webpage can't open?
All webpage can browse when to delete the file /etc/nftables.conf.

```
sudo rm /etc/nftables.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stopped your PC from receiving any packets:

```
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
```

Deleting this file won't help, you either have to reboot or run this command: `sudo nft flush ruleset`